# the server could not find the requested resource (post namespaces) over ssh

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

Hello I have a terraform proyect, currently I download the proyect in the host and I use terraform apply there, but I want to try to make this using ssh, in order to do that I have the following code:

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "main" {
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "root"
    private_key = var.private_key
    host        = var.host
    host_key    = var.host_key
  }
  metadata {
    name = var.namespace
  }

}
```

I didn't have password, because I only use `ssh -i privatekey user@host` to get access to that host.

But I get the following error:

```
Error: the server could not find the requested resource (post namespaces)
```

the provider is the following:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path    = "~/.kube/config"
  config_context = "microk8s"
}
```

and the file and the context are correct.

**EDIT**

Terraform looks kubeconfig in the localhost instead of the remote host.

How can I solve this and apply changes remotely using ssh?

Thanks

Comment: The error message does not match the provided config in the question. Please update with what is producing the error message.

Comment: I think is about that, because terraform is looking for the kubeconfig in my local machine instead of the remote host